# Register broadcast receiver with category

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have a broadcast receiver which works perfectly, but I am tasked with adding categories to it.

To do it in manifest is in the following way:

```
<intent-filter>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.SOME_A" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.SOME_B" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

How do I do this programmatically?
I am only able to add intent filter to it while defining it.

```
context.registerReceiver(myReceiver, "com.test.some_test_filter");
```

To send an intent to this receiver I would just use the [addCategory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addCategory(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for later reference.
This is the way to [add category](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#addCategory(java.lang.String))